# Swift How to add a working clock?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have this clock

[image]

and I want to make something like it. I want it to work in each second, I mean by work to start full and then becomes empty gradually.

#### What I have tried

I created a custom view and added a `UIBezierPath` like the following:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
        let endAngle: CGFloat = 80.0
        let radius: CGFloat = 80.0

        let path2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path2.fill()
    }
}
```

and all I get is:

[image]

I don't know where is the wrong (maybe my whole approach is wrong), I tried to change the values to start angle as 0 and the end angle as 90, but kept having the same shape.

#### Updat3 1

after people suggested that i should change degrees to radians, i changed my code like this

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func degreesToRadians (number: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {



        let startAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(0)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(270)

        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0


        let path2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)



        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path2.fill()

    }
}
```

but the result is this:

[image]

you can compare the result with the image that i want, the cut is not as i want. please look to the picture, i don't know how to say it in english

Comment: Angles need to be in radians and not in degrees.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30292047/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func degreesToRadians (number: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let startAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(0)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(270)

        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)



        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path.addLineToPoint(center)
        path.fill()

    }
}
let c = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

... see this line

```
path.addLineToPoint(center)
```

Comment: is this `addLineToPoint` the most beautiful function i didn't know about or what ? ? ?? wow wow wow thanks

Comment: could you please check my new question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747391/calling-a-timer-to-update-the-path-on-swift