# calling a timer to update the path on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I had this code and it is working nice

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func degreesToRadians (number: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let startAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(0)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(270)

        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)



        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path.addLineToPoint(center)
        path.fill()

    }
}
```

but as you see the values are dynamic (hard coded) I want to change the values depending on a timer, so i added a timer and a function to update the values. my code becomes like this:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!


    }

    let startAngle: Double = 0
    var counter = 0
    let numberOfMinutes = 60
    var path: UIBezierPath?
    var endAngle : Double {
        get {
            counter++
            return 360 - Double(360/60 * (counter))
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    func degreesToRadians (number: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(startAngle)
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(endAngle)
        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
            endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
            clockwise: true)
        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path!.addLineToPoint(center)
        path!.fill()
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }

    func update() {
        print("counter = \(counter)")
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(startAngle)
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(endAngle)
        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
            endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
            clockwise: true)
        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        path!.addLineToPoint(center)
        path!.fill()
    }

}
```

my problem is that : **first** the circle on the screen doesn't change, it is being drawn from the first call, then it is not being changed,

and secondly, i have this on the log:

```
counter = 1
counter = 2
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 17 00:51:51  grab a table[5132] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
counter = 3
```

i don't know why it is throwing these errors after the **third** iteration.

what am i doing wrong in the timer? should I construct the path everytime the function update gets called?

Comment: FYI - please use the proper tags for your questions.

Comment: @rmaddy i am sorry, i have added objective-c because i believe that swift and objective-c are sisters.

Comment: But none of your questions have anything at all to do with Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy okay i won't argue. sorry again

Comment: Don't you have to change some parameters of your drawing for the circle to change? As it stands it seems like you are drawing a circle then repeatedly drawing the same circle on top of it over and over.

Comment: @beyowulf the endAngleValue is a computed property. each time it gives different values.

Comment: But it's the same color as what's behind it. You're painting a green circle then painting a green half circle on top of it. So, it's showing up as a green circle.

Comment: @beyowulf i supposed that, so i deleted the point using the function `        path?.removeAllPoints()` but kept having the same problem

Comment: @beyowulf please if you have any other suggestion tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do all of your drawing in drawRect. drawRect is the function that pushes pixels to the screen. If you want to dynamically change how your view is drawn, you should create properties that you can set (most likely by a view controller), then implement their didSet function and call setNeedsDisplay, so your view is redrawn with the new parameters. For example:

```
var lineWidth: CGFloat {
        didSet {

            self.setNeedsDisplay()

        }
    }
```

Or

```
var circlePath: UIBezierPath {
            didSet {

                self.setNeedsDisplay()

            }
        }
```

Keep circlePath as a variable then change drawRect to

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        if self.circlePath !=nil{
          self.circlePath.addLineToPoint(center)
          self.circlePath.fill()
        }
    }
```

Then move

```
func degreesToRadians (number: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
let startAngle: Double = 0
    var counter = 0
    let numberOfMinutes = 60
    var endAngle : Double {
        get {
            counter++
            return 360 - Double(360/60 * (counter))
        }

    }
func update() {
        print("counter = \(counter)")
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(startAngle)
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(endAngle)
        let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
            endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
            clockwise: true)
        self.circleView.circlePath = path
    }
```

To the view controller that your view appears in. Get a reference to it and call it circleView. Then in viewDidLoad place:

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
```

Comment: i got error  property self.path not initialized by super.init call

Comment: Try making it optional or initializing it

Comment: i fixed that error by declaring the path before supper, but still got the same behavior

Comment: What are you setting path equal to? Where are you changing the path? I'm explaining a coding paradigm. You can't just copy and paste and expect it to work.