# Why isn't the text drawn?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I draw the text using Swift String.drawWithRect method.
It works fine when drawing in drawRect().
But when I place the code inside dispatch_after method it isn't drawn.

Here is the code:

```
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(2)*Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()){

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12),
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(),
                     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

        let string = "Test"

        let x = 100.0
        let y = 100.0

        string.drawWithRect(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)
    }
```

I guess it's related to drawing context but can't figure out what to do.
How to switch context, in order to draw text using dispatch_after?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You cannot do asynchronous drawing within `drawRect`. The context is specially setup for you within `drawRect` - so calling functions after `drawRect` has happened will likely lead to a crash.

Comment: In actual code I draw scale marks in a for loop and I want them to appear one after another with a little delay.

Comment: Okay, well that's not something `drawRect` is designed to do. You'll probably want to look into using a `CAShapeLayer` instead to draw your scale marks, and then change the `strokeEnd` property to create your effect - or use a `CADisplayLink` to re-draw your view for the intermediate steps. My answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34957671/2976878) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34964241/2976878) might be useful for this.

Comment: Thanks. I've used CAShapeLayer for animation.