# Animate UIBezierPaths- not working- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I am trying to create an arrow that animates together. But, there are two problems:

1.The lines are not animating, the whole arrow is just appearing on screen

2.The arrow is filled in black, not just the outlines (which I am aiming for)

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

//set up lines
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50.5, y: 158.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221.5, y: 158.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 171.5, y: 108.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 197.5, y: 82.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 292.5, y: 177.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 197.5, y: 272.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 171.5, y: 246.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 221.5, y: 196.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50.5, y: 196.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50.5, y: 158.5))
UIColor.black.setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

// set up animation
let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

animation2.fromValue = 0.0
animation2.toValue = 1.0
animation2.duration = 2.5
shapeLayer.add(animation2, forKey: "drawLineAnimation")

eeView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

If anyone could help me with their of those that would be amazing. Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers,
Theo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this sequence:

```
shapeLayer.add(animation2, forKey: "drawLineAnimation")
eeView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

You cannot add an animation to a layer and then add the layer to the interface. You can only add animation to a layer that is *already* in the interface.

Also, you need to set the shape layer's `fillColor` and `strokeColor`.

Here's actual code. In one place, you would say something like this:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    eeView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    self.shape = shapeLayer // self.shape is a property
```

Then, at some *later* time, you would say:

```
    let shapeLayer = self.shape!
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    // ... rest of your code goes here: create path, add path to shape layer ...
    // ... create animation, add animation to shape layer
```

[image]

Comment: hmm... that didn't seem to fix it. still just appearing all at once on the view. thanks so much for your answer tho!

Comment: It would also be better if you would give the shape layer a `frame`.

Comment: thanks a ton!! This is so helpful. I'll implement this when I get on my computer and then give you the check. We need more people like you on this platform.