# I am making a program for circular progress bar using UIBezierPath is it a good practise or not?

Tags: swift

**Taking a view roundView and making it round and then draw a circular path along roundView and giving a start stroke and giving end stroke at time method. Is it a correct way of doing**

```
    var count = 0.0
    var circlePath: UIBezierPath!
    var roundView: UIView!
    var circleShape: CAShapeLayer!
    var x: Timer!
    var headerView: HeaderView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // setup()
        roundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
        roundView.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2

        // bezier path
        circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  radius: roundView.frame.size.width / 2,
                                  startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * Double.pi),
                                  endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * Double.pi),
                                  clockwise: true)
        // circle shape
        circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
        circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
        circleShape.borderWidth = 10
        circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleShape.lineWidth = 10
        // set start and end values
        circleShape.strokeStart = 0.0
        x = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }
```

Add end stroke

```
@objc func update() {
        // Something cool
        if count >= 1{
            x.invalidate()

        }
        count = count + 0.01
        self.label.text = String(Int(count * 100))
        circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(count)
        roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
        // add subview
        self.tableView.addSubview(roundView)
        print(count)
    }
```

Comment: i don't see why not

Comment: You should use CABasicAnimation and animate strokeEnd. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292047/2303865

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about good or bad practice, it often means if the approach is efficient, safe or not. Say doing a force unwrap is bad practice, and using `if let` is a good practice.

In your case, a circular progress bar is nothing other than a view with some layer or path on top, which finally formed the bar liked view. It is the correct way of doing it and it is not a bad practice.